# Jquery disable theming for a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, themes

Is there a way to disable the theming on one element in the page?

I have some Jquery UI element but I need to have one of these element not themed. How to do that?

Comment: can you give the sample of the UI element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JQuery UI is made up of some standard CSS framework classes.  You can remove the UI themes from an element by turning off those classes.  Check out the [JQuery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming/API) to see a list of the classes and decide which one it is you want to remove (using Firebug makes this pretty easy as well, you can identify which UI classes are applied).  `ui-widget` and `ui-state-default` are likely choices.

Once you know the class, just use JQuery's `removeClass()` to get it off:

```
$('element').removeClass('ui-widget');
```

Comment: By removing the class, I won't be able to drag-and-drop I guess and this is problematic. In fact I want the Modal Dialog to be themed and not all other controls that can be dragged.

Comment: give the control an id and overwrite the css

Comment: Hard to go because the JQuery Draggrable plug-in use Class for its manipulation.

Answer (score 21):

I know this question is old but it looks like jQuery Mobile now has a way to get around this:

```
data-role="none"
```

Add that to any form or button element to remove jQuery Mobile Theming.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html

Comment: Perfect ! Thats the only solution to disable the "Javascript parser" of jquery mobile to read your DOM element.

Comment: This is definitely the answer which should be marked as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As of 1.3, it looks adding the attribute

```
data-theme="none"
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way ;) 
You have to remove all declaration of addClass in jQuery JavaScript file.

Find a proper section (for me was acccordion) and delete from js code addClass().

It work for me ;)

Comment: The problem with that solution is that the class is required to be able to drag-and-drop with JQuery UI. I cannot remove it.

Comment: i don't know about drag and drop, but for the accordion i'm removing all the .ui-state* and all .ui-cornner* classes and it's working just fine!