# Remove Button from tel link

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

http://w5webdesigns.com/bwick/

I want the phone number to display as a clickable link that will activate the system phone, that works so far but I need to remove the button so all you see is the phone number. How does that work?

```
 <a href="tel:1518279392">518.279.392</a>
```

Comment: What do you mean remove the button? If you don't add the `data-role="button"` attribute it shouldn't be styled as a button to begin with.

Comment: I do not have the data-role="button" attribute on, all the code is just how you see it, some how it is appending the button to the footer in the <a href>

Comment: It would seem that adding an <h> tag around it gives me the desired effect. That is odd that it works like that. I think I will print off the CSS files and get to know them a little better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery mobile applies their brand of mobile friendly ui styling.  You can either inspect the element with Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools to pinpoint which styles you don't want and then specifically write your own CSS that will override those styles.  Or you can try the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2128383/1408356).

Comment: Looks like I need to become more friendly with JQ Mobile's css files.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `data-role="none"` to your tag

```
 <a data-role="none" href="tel:1518279392">518.279.392</a>
```

In general when using an anchor tag unless you specify a `data-role="button"` jQuery Mobile will leave it alone. However it seems that when you place it in your header or footer jQuery Mobile will enhance it regardless. Explicitly adding the data-role="none" attribute will stop jQuery Mobile from enhancing it. Another *trick* you can do to prevent jQuery Mobile from enhancing markup in your header/footer is to wrap it in a `div`.

```
 <div><a  href="tel:1518279392">518.279.392</a></div>
```