# How to tell jQuery UI not to apply it's styling to specific elements

Tags: jquery-ui

This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128316/jquery-disable-theming-for-a-specific-element), so this is a dupe but it's been 4 years since it was asked.  We are using jQuery UI 1.9.0, and I need a way for it to not apply themeing to certain elements (specifically `<button>`).  How can I tell jQuery to NOT apply themeing?  Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems jQuery UI automatically applies themeing to all elements on the page.

In dupe question people suggested adding `data-theme="none"` or `data-role="none"` attributes, but neither of them work.  They also suggested removing the `ui-*` classes, but that is a hack and not a clean solution.

EDIT:  I want jQuery to *not* apply any of the `ui-*` classes to my `<button>`.  I also want to avoid having to modify the jQuery UI CSS file.

Comment: jQuery UI's themes are just CSS, so you would override it the way you'd override any CSS. There aren't any special tricks, switches, or hacks to do this.

Comment: This is indeed a dupe, the original question is still relevant even if it is four years old.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I want jQuery to not apply any classes to my buttons.

Comment: jquery-ui doesnt automatically do anything. you have to select things and call functions to generate the ui elements... somewhere you have something like $("button").button().

Comment: @JMS10, read the answers in the duplicate (well, the ones that do not target jQuery Mobile). Removing the classes will neuter some of jQuery UI's features, like interactions (e.g. drag and drop). I don't think what you want to achieve is possible.

Comment: @happytimeharry, thanks a lot!  That's where I went wrong.  I was thinking it was automatically doing it, but that's not the case.  I changed my selector to `$('button:not([data-theme="none"])').button();`  It was deep in our code so I had to search for it.

Comment: @JMS10 there you go buddy!!!