# How to jquery disable theming on particular controls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

The web page uses jquery ui widgets for date picking etc as well se for popup context menus. For this, the page needs to refer to a jquery css. However, we prefer to use default browser style for submit buttons on a form. We are able to mark them manually. On the other hand, it is quite ok if styles are applied on the buttons which are part of the date picker widget.

I have tried several approaches like [removeClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128316/jquery-disable-theming-for-a-specific-element), `className`.`replace` in `document`.`ready()` or `data-role=no` but it does not work as expected. For example, it removes the style from the normal state but not from the hover or selected state of the buttons.

So how to disable jquery-ui them on selected buttons?

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7amcfz9h/)

Answer (score 1):

In jQueryUI css (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css) change all selectors pointing to your button to exlude marked ones with `:not()` pseudoselector, for example:

```
.ui-state-default:not([type="submit"])
```

If you dont want to modify oryginal CSS (for ex. it's from CDN) after including it load another CSS (local one) with rules copied from oryginal but regarding only modified buttons and after each parameter do `!important` and reset every rule. Weak solution but works, you better end up editing source.

> it is quite unrealistic to roll back to the browser-default button
>   style

Than style them

```
.ui-state-default[type="submit"] { /* rules for excluded buttons */ }
```

Also `[type="submit"]` is an exclusion marker yourself proposed, excludor could be an class or whatever else for example:

```
.ui-state-default:not(.marked) { /* in jQueryUI */ }
.ui-state-default.marked { /* in your styles */ }
```

Comment: That means I need to alter original CSS? Is there a way how to do it while still using untouched original CSS?

Comment: After loading oryginal css include modified css with rules just for marked buttons (see edited answer)

Comment: Not happy of that and it is quite unrealistic to roll back to the browser-default button style as each browser is unique. Thanks to your insight I have managed to do it by few unbinds of jquery event handlers and redefinition of jquery prototypes. It's far from perfect but have nothing better on hand.

Comment: @alik So instead of modyfing library CSS you've changed it's JS. Could you share that as answer?

Comment: Yeah, but the original JS files are intact (which is one of my requirements). I will share the code later on if nobody comes with a conceptually better solution.

Comment: @alik @ "it is quite unrealistic to roll back to the browser-default button style" see edit about that