# How to disable jquery-ui (widget) for a specific element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I use Jquery-UI and accordingly the `selectmenu`-widget in my project. Can I disable the widget for a specific element, so that the select look and functionality returns to native?

I tried solutions mentioned in [Jquery disable theming for a specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128316/jquery-disable-theming-for-a-specific-element) but without success. `data-role: none` is not doing any change, and I can't simply remove `ui-classes` because the widget creates a whole new element which acts like a proxy for the select and so the select itself does not have any classes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will need a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also please review: https://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#method-disable

Comment: @Twisty the disable/destroy method is one solution. It didn't work for me at first, since the inital element got hidden by jquery-ui and I had to show() it manually again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by manually destroying the selectmenu-element and displaying the initial element again at `documentReady()`.

I would be glad to hear about a better solution since this one is hacky and involves problems, e.g. at responsiveness if the element should be displayed just at a specific screen size, you have to handle it again manually in your function where you render the initial element back.

Comment: If you want a better solution, you will need to provide a proper example. I suspect a selector can more acutely select the elements you want and avoid the one you do not want when you initialize SelectMenu.